Multiple subscriptions with async iterators of v2.0 RPC notifications
First of all, thank you so much for the job done in the v2.0 release of the Solana web3 package.
So much improvements here, amazing!
I'm actually a Node.JS developer, and I do have a script that uses the v1.0 "onProgramAccountChange" and "onLogs" rpc methods to react when some events happen on the blockchain.
With the v2.0 release, I understand that I should now use the async iterator-based methods like "accountNotifications().subscribe()".
Unfortunately I'm not so used to leverage async iterators, and so I'm unable to translate my v1.0 codebase to v2.0.
My script is actually listening on the "onProgramAccountChange" events and do stuff when events happen. The script listen on 4 different events, and do stuff for each event.
How can I do the same with the v2.0 release? If I'm not mistaken, subscribing to a given method (like accountNotifications) and then looping through it will "block" the thread of the script, so I don't see how I can subscribe to multiple methods within a given script?
Can you please help?

I am also using v1 sdk for listening to around 100 accounts for logs simultaneously using onLogs, will it be fine, or is it too many connections already?
As there is no way i could find for checking the individual subscription health?

Is my answer below what you needed, @user1448932? If so, click that ‘accept’ checkmark, when you have a chance.

The subscription API in @solana/web3.js returns an AsyncIterable that you can poll using flow control structures native to JavaScript.
const accountNotifications = await rpcSubscriptions
  .accountNotifications(address)
  .subscribe({ abortSignal });
for await (const notification of accountNotifications) {
  // Do something with each `notification`
}

You can think of for...await itself as a promise that settles when the loop returns or an error is thrown. Seen from that perspective, how would you fire off multiple of them? The same way you would await multiple promises!
await Promise.all([
  (async () => {
    const accountNotifications = await rpcSubscriptions
      .accountNotifications(address)
      .subscribe({ abortSignal });
    for await (const notification of accountNotifications) {
      // Do something with each account notification.
    }
  })(),
  (async () => {
    const logsNotifications = await rpcSubscriptions
      .logsNotifications({ mentions: [address] })
      .subscribe({ abortSignal });
    for await (const notification of logsNotifications) {
      // Do something with each logs notification.
    }
  })(),
  // ...and more.
]);

